# Converting OMP to Pthreads in c

Tags: c, pthreads, openmp

I have the following section of code running in OMP to calculate Dijkstra algorithm, i would like to convert it to Pthreads. I understand that for pthreads i would have to divide the work evenly against the number of input threads and join it back up. Could someone please show me how to create this?

```
//Set max nThreads
    omp_set_num_threads(nThreads);
    omp_set_schedule(omp_sched_auto, G->N/100);
        dijkstra(G, 0, 0);

void dijkstra(graph* G, long initial_node, char debug)
{
    long i,j,k;
    long aN; //actualNode
    G->D[initial_node] = 0;
    aN = initial_node;

    if(debug){
        printf("Running dijkstra on graph\n");
        printGraph(G);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < G->N; i++)
    {
        G->visited[aN] = VISITED;

        if(debug){
            printf("It[%d] aN [%d]",i, aN); printStatus(G); printf("\n");
        }

        //Find all nodes connected to aN
        #pragma omp parallel for schedule(runtime)
        for(j=0;j<G->N;j++){
            if( (G->node[aN][j] != NO_CONN) ){
                if( (G->D[aN] + G->node[aN][j]) < G->D[j] ){
                    G->D[j] = (G->D[aN] + G->node[aN][j]);
                }
            }
        }

        aN = getNextNode(G);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not post the same question multiple times. Edit the original question to improve it or, if you need some time to improve it, delete the original, improve it, and post it again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting OMP to PThreads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52637369/converting-omp-to-pthreads)

Comment: At this point: Delete all but one of your three questions and improve it as much as possible by editing.

Comment: I thought you had done some pthreads effort but I see now you have only shown your OpenMP code. You should show what you have tried with pthreads so far.